# Where should I put procedures that operate on multiple structs?

Tags: c, organization

I'm writing a game in C which that has a lattice/node system in it. I'm struggling to see where to put procedures that operate on both the lattice and node at the same time.

Node.h

```
struct Node
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node*    CreateNode(void);
void            DestroyNode(struct Node* n);
```

Lattice.h

```
extern struct Node;

struct Lattice
{
    struct Node* root;
};

struct Lattice* CreateLattice(void);
void            DestroyLattice(struct Lattice* l);
```

And I have two procedures I need to put somewhere:

```
bool    InsertNode(struct Lattice* l, struct Node* n);
bool    FindNode(struct Lattice* l, int x, int y, struct Node** on);
```

I know that i could technically put the procedures in either file it doesn't matter, but i'm new to organizing C code, where do these normally go?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's largely opinion. However, as `Lattice` itself depends on `Node`, it would seem more natural to associate your functions with `Lattice`.

Comment: I agree, it's largely opinion.  Another possibility is to create a `util.h` that houses functions that go beyond creation/deletion of the data structures.

Comment: @AdrianMole Very interesting, but hypothetically if the Node depended on Lattice too, what about then?

Comment: It doesn't seem like either InsertNode or FindNode do anything to the Node.  They are just operating on the Lattice, so group them with the Lattice.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, but what if they did do something to the Node, what would you group them with then?

Comment: @RichardBamford You'd have to be able to provide a specific use case; for the general case my gut feeling is that they should be refactored so that they don't manipulate both!

Comment: @WilliamPursell hm interesting, but i think the problem is not to do with the functions but to do with how we group them together. The solution i'm using at the moment is to put them in a general module, for example SpatialPartioning.h. This module imports both Node.h and Lattice.h along with some free-floating functions. It seems to do well however this situation can occur when there is no module to be found which is annoying.

Answer (score -1):

A function to "import" data into an object of type X from an object of type Y would generally belong in the library that's most associated with type X.  A function to "export" data from an object of type X to an object of type Y would generally belong in the library that's most associated with type X.  A function to "convert" data from type X to type Y may belong in a library that's not particularly associated with either type.  Even though all three functions may behave identically, it may sometimes be more natural to describe the *primary expected usage* of a function as importing, exporting, or conversion.

Note also, by the way, that although older compilers, or those intended to be compatible with them, wouldn't require this, the Standard requires that any function prototype which accepts a pointer to a structure type in an argument be preceded by some other mention of that structure type.

If one writes:

```
struct foo;
void test(struct foo *p);
```

that will declare `test` as accepting a pointer to the same `struct foo` type that will be used elsewhere in the compilation unit.  If the first line were omitted, and nothing prior to the `test()` prototype mentioned `struct foo`, the Standard would specify that the prototype be treated as accepting a pointer to a structure type that can't possibly exist anywhere else in the universe, making it impossible to call the function except by passing a `void*`, or define a function that matches the prototype declaration.

I am hard pressed to imagine any situation where the Standard's treatment of local structure tags that don't match global ones would genuinely be useful, or what downside there would be to having a quality compiler extend the language to behave as thought there had been a file-scope `struct foo`; declaration unless invoked in a "pedantic" mode, but for whatever reason such an extension is not among those implemented by gcc and clang, and it will thus be necessary to explicitly include a file-scope declaration if one wants to be compatible with such compilers.